# Databricks Pyspark - Java heap space error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, nlp, databricks

I am encountering a problem with Databricks that I'm unable to resolve. The error that is get is: `An error occurred while calling o554.fit. : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`  This led me to suggest that there is not enough room for the required computation (I'm doing a Naive Bayes Classification). However, the data that I am using is not that big (150 mb for testing purposes). What could be the problem?

I tried:

- forcing garbage collection
- getting a bigger cluster/smaller cluster/more workers/less workers
- creating a new cluster
- restarting the cluster
- clearing the cache
- spark.sparkContext.stop()

The weird thing is that the code used to run before, but now it remains stuck in this situation. When checking the memory usage in the Spark UI metric tab, I can see that it is very high, even when just starting the cluster. Any suggestions about what else I could try?

EDIT: I'm using Spark 2.4.5

full error code:

```
<command-2419111842344626> in <module>
----> 1 nbModel = nb.fit(trainingData)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 295         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    296         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    297         return self._copyValues(model)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    290         """
    291         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 292         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o554.fit.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes$$anonfun$trainWithLabelCheck$1.apply(NaiveBayes.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes$$anonfun$trainWithLabelCheck$1.apply(NaiveBayes.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$$anonfun$14.apply(Instrumentation.scala:277)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes.trainWithLabelCheck(NaiveBayes.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes.train(NaiveBayes.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes.train(NaiveBayes.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

EDIT 2: Pictures as requested

[DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGF5G.png)
[Jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4NNJ.png)[Executor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0X36.png)

Comment: repartition your input data and increase executor memory (especially increase the percentage of application/working memory spark.memory.fraction)

Comment: @kavetiraviteja, thank you for your reply! The spark.executor.memory is set to 7284m. Would you suggest increasing it further? As to the re-partitioning, that didn't seem to solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: yes, increase spark.executor.memory and also increase the percentage of (spark.memory.fraction) ... default is 0.6 you  can increase to 0.7-0.8 ... if there is no caching of dataframe in your code.

Comment: @kavetiraviteja set the spark.executor.memory to max and the spark.memory.fraction to 0.8. This causes the error to occur a few lines of code further down. This changes the error to ```Job Aborted. Caused by: OutOfMemoryError``` So no luck so far

Comment: please update your question with DAG and executor stats.

Comment: Alright, I think I added what you requested. I hope it is helpful

Comment: by looking DAG you have a lot of shuffle happening in your code and the default count of partitions after shuffle is 200 (sometimes this can cause OOM if your data is skewed) try to increase spark.sql.shuffle.partition.count.

Comment: By looking at Jobs status .... some task are launched with 0 data and some have launche with huge data and i see that some tasks are very fast and some took >1 min so it clearly indicates data skewness

Comment: one thing peculiar in your executor's picture is RDD blocks are 0 ... it means no tasks with data is launched or some other issue.